# Question about proof that finite-dimensional subspaces of normed vector spaces are direct summands

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am reading [a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104440/finite-dimensional-subspaces-of-normed-vector-spaces-are-direct-summands) that finite-dimensional subspaces of normed vector spaces have closed direct sum complements. This is the proof:

> Let $\{e_1, ..., e_n\}$ be a basis for $\mathcal M$. Every $x \in 
>  \mathcal M$ has then a unique representation $$x = \alpha_1(x)e_1 +...+
>  \alpha_n(x)e_n.$$ Each $\alpha_i$ is a continuous linear functional on
>    $\mathcal M$ (a linear map from  finite dimensional space is always
>    continuous) which extends to a member of $\mathcal X^*$,  by the
>    Hahn-Banach theorem ($\mathcal X^*$ is the dual of $\mathcal X$). Let
>    $\mathcal N$ be the intersection of the null spaces of these exten­sions. Then $\mathcal X = \mathcal M\oplus \mathcal N$.

I follow it until the last sentence. Clearly $\mathcal N$ is closed, as it is the intersection of closed sets (the inverse of $0$ under any continuous function, and in particular any linear functional on a vector space, is closed). Also it is easy to see that $\mathcal M \cap \mathcal N= \{0\}$, since if some $m\in\mathcal M$ is in every null space, it must have the zero coefficient for every basis vector, and so it must be zero.

My question: Why do we have $\mathcal X =\mathcal M + \mathcal N$? This seems to only hold if the extension given by Hahn-Banach is zero off of $\mathcal M$, but I see no reason why this should be the case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is how I would do the proof, in a more explicit way:

After you extend all the $\alpha_i$, you can use them to define a bounded projection onto $\mathcal M$:
$$
P(x)=\alpha_1(x)e_1+\cdots+\alpha_n(x)e_n.
$$
Now you let $\mathcal N=\ker P$. Then any $x\in\mathcal X$ satisfies
$$
x=Px+(x-Px)\in\mathcal M+\mathcal N.
$$

Note that from this construction it is clear that $\mathcal N=\displaystyle\bigcap_1^n\ker\alpha_j$, so the original answer was right.

Comment: $ $ Thanks! $ $

Comment: Hi @Martin Argerami does it proves that if $X$ is normed, $M$ is a finite dimensional subspace of $X$ then there's a projection $P\in B(X)$ such that $Im P=M$ ?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ $

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to be more clear. Where does the argument use that $X$ is complete? And, not sure what you mean by "write $x$ that way".

Comment: Since there are claims that help show that there exist a projection, if we're given that X is bnach.So I don't recognize how we deduce that there is a projection that its imge equal M. And I meant, ahy we can write $x=\alfa_1 (x)e_1+...\alfa_n(x) e_n$. @Martin Argerami

Comment: Because $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ are a basis. A basis of a vector space allows you to write a vector $x$ as a linear combination $x=\sum_j\alpha_je_j$, in a unique way.

Comment: Hi @Martin Argerami can you please tell how to do this (which is supposed to be the same question you answered here), using the hint? Many thanms https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4117484/showing-existence-of-a-projective

Comment: The hint is to do the case $n=1$ first.

Comment: Yes, then to do the same proof you did? @Martin Argerami

Comment: Yes, that's what they are telling you.