# Showing existence of a projective

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, projection

Let $X$ be a normed space and $Y$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $X$.
Show that there is a projective $P\in B(X)$ such that $Im P=Y$.

Hint: First Solve for $dimY=1$ then generalize the solution for any finite dimensioanl spaces.

Here since $Y$is  finite dimensional subspace of a normed space so it is closed.
However we are not given that $X$ is banach, so we cannot use any theorem about projective in banach spaces!.

**The question stated in [Question about proof that finite-dimensional subspaces of normed vector spaces are direct summands](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407969/question-about-proof-that-finite-dimensional-subspaces-of-normed-vector-spaces-a)
Suggests another way to show this.

Can someone kindly, explain how to solve the question using the hint.

Comment: If you really want to use Banach spaces, can you not embed $X$ in its completion $\hat{X}$?  The embedding won't be closed, but since $Y$ is finite-dimensional rather than a general closed subspace, passing to $\hat{X}$ doesn't change anything...

Comment: I don't think involving Banach spaces will be useful. This isn't a question about completeness. In a Hilbert space, you could use an orthonormal basis though.

Comment: If you read that proof carefully, they are using the one dimensional case to look for those $\alpha_i$.

Comment: I did not much understand what you mean..They said that the other question solves my question, I don't see how.@Arctic Char

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Use the Hahn-Banach theorem. Note that it doesn't involve Banach spaces anyway.

So what about the $1$-dimensional case? You didn't write what you did with this hint.

Comment: It's not the right place to explain another question, but let me just say that $x \mapsto \alpha_1(x)e_1 +\ldots+ \alpha_n(x)e_n$ is the required projection, where $\alpha_j$'s are extended to the whole space.